# Alert once an activity is detected

Tags: matlab, audio, alert

My program is to record automatically once a sound is detected, I want to put an audible alert once the program starts recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [beep](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/beep.html) as a quick solution.  If you have a particular sound file you'd like to use, you can use [wavread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/wavread.html) to load the file into Matlab and [soundsc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/soundsc.html) to play it.

Comment: FYI, `wavread` is deprecated (as of R2013a). One should use the more general [`audioread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

A little fun for OS X users only – you can use the built-in text-to-speech terminal command [`say`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/say.1.html) in conjunction with Matlab's [`unix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unix.html):

```
unix('say starting');
```

or, if you like:

```
if ismac
    unix('say starting');
else
    beep;
end
```

In addition one can play all of the built-in OS X alert sounds using [`afplay`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/afplay.1.html). The sounds are [AIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format) files and are located at `/System/Library/Sounds/`. Here is how to play the famous [Sosumi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sosumi) alert:

```
unix('afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Sosumi.aiff');
```